# Symfony2 presents rendering different views in dev and prod environment

Tags: symfony

I designing an programming a website using Symfony2. I completed some parts and checked the client side in both dev and prod environment. In the first time everything was fine and I saw same result in both environments, But after sum changes in views (I'm using Twig with [Three-level Inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance)) such as adding sum other stylesheets in "stylesheets" block, dev environment works fine but in prod environment no stylesheets added and its using old data. I cleared cache and log manually from both path "app/cache/dev" and "app/cache/prod" ... but nothing changed. I removed all stylesheets in block and cleared chache again old data is still there!

Any suggestion?

Comment: hai... where are your stylesheets saved? in the web/css?? or is it in their respective bundle/Resourse/public/css ??

Comment: All css placed in right place but finally I found that permission of some file caused problem so when I deleted cache some file was still there but cPanel filemanager didn't show any error. At last I cleared cache with shell_exec

Comment: so is it working now..??

Comment: yes! I'm new here, should I delete question?

Comment: no don't delete the Question.. but answer the question yourself so that it will be more helpful for others who experience this situation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about removing cache files. I had been removing cache files via cPanel filemanager. It gave "all files removed successfully" but they didn't. So I found another way to clear cache. I used shell_exec:

```
shell_exec('rm -r app/cache/prod');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from clearing the cache, make sure you publish your assets:

```
app/console assets:install --symlink web
app/console assetic:dump
```